# md-menu detect click outside

Tags: angularjs, menu, click, material-design

I'm using Angular Material and md-menu. I can run a function by pressing the menu button, but not outside. How to execute a function by clicking outside the menu when the menu is open?

The code:

```
                    <md-menu>
                        <div ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event);">
                            <div>
                                <md-icon md-svg-src="1.svg"></md-icon>
                            </div>
                            {{ items }}
                        </div>
                        <md-menu-content width="2">
                            <md-menu-item>
                                <md-button ng-click="funa()">item1</md-button>
                            </md-menu-item>
                            <md-menu-item>
                                <md-button ng-click="funb()">item2</md-button>
                            </md-menu-item>
                        </md-menu-content>
                    </md-menu>
```

When I click outside the menu, always closed and i can't run another action/function.

Thanks a lot!